# Where can I find the Salesforce documentation for the different API versions?

Tags: api, documentation

I'm in the process of upgrading the API versions of several classes and components. Some classes are jumping up several versions.

Where can I find the Salesforce documentation for the different API versions?

```
    <apiVersion>37.0</apiVersion>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do belive that it is available in every developer guide as well as [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm#rn_apex_new_classes_methods?edition=&impact=) for a release in [Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/glossary_apex.htm) and Release notes respectively.

[image]